# AsyncTask como subclase

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Tengo un `AsyncTask` el cual funciona bien pero quiero implementar otro `AsyncTask`. Mi duda es si se puede hacer dentro de una clase dos subclases y que cada una de las subclases  implemente `AsyncTask`. ¿Es mi planteamiento correcto?

Answer (score 1):

Si puedes hacerlo,  pero solo puedes llamar a tu segunda `Asynctask` desde los métodos

> onProgressUpdate()

o desde

> onPostExecute()

de tu primer `AsyncTask`.

Sería algo así desde tu primer `Asynctask`:

```
 @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String result){
         super.onPostExecute(result);
         llamadaSegundoHilo(misParametros)
    }
```

Comment: Agradesco tu respuesta JeCuRo y las correciones :D

Comment: Nada para eso estamos :) , si crees que la respuesta es válida no olvides aceptarla pulsando sobre  ✓    suerte !!